# Swift 4.0 Tesseract OCR SIGABRT error

Tags: swift, tesseract, sigabrt

Im trying to implement Tesseract within a project on Swift 4.0 but am getting a SIGABRT error which is completely divorced from any @IBActions or Outlets

The instantiation of the Tesseract object is giving me the issue

```
let tesseract = G8Tesseract(language: "eng")
```

[instantiating a Tesseract Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUCMN.png)

The SIGABRT error is happening with the following method call

```
- (BOOL)configEngine
{
    GenericVector<STRING> tessKeys;
    for( NSString *key in self.configDictionary.allKeys ){
        tessKeys.push_back(STRING(key.UTF8String));
    }

    GenericVector<STRING> tessValues;
    for( NSString *val in self.configDictionary.allValues ){
        tessValues.push_back(STRING(val.UTF8String));
    }

     int count = (int)self.configFileNames.count;
    const char **configs = count ? (const char **)malloc(sizeof(const 
char 
*) * count) : NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        configs[i] = ((NSString*)self.configFileNames[i]).UTF8String;
    }
    int returnCode = _tesseract->Init(self.absoluteDataPath.UTF8String, 
self.language.UTF8String,

(tesseract::OcrEngineMode)self.engineMode,
                                      (char **)configs, count,
                                      &tessKeys, &tessValues,
                                      false);
    if (configs != nullptr) {
        free(configs);
    }
    return returnCode == 0;
}
```

[Method with Tesseract Initilization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5z6B.png)

Im guessing the real issue here is that the Tesseract Library is just out of date and am hoping someone might have some insight.  To reiterate this is not a typical SIGABRT error using Xcode since commenting out the instantiating method avoids any errors while the app is running

Outside of the it being a SIGABRT error here is the resulting error info:

```
2018-02-28 18:48:20.585396-0800 KeySnap[2446:10989] [MC] Lazy loading 
NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework
2018-02-28 18:48:20.586598-0800 KeySnap[2446:10989] [MC] Loaded 
MobileCoreServices.framework
2018-02-28 18:48:26.347510-0800 KeySnap[2446:10989] [MC] System group 
container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is 
/Users/looker/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BBC86BAD-13B3-
471D-97E6-
C35A8E53C0A9/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/
systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2018-02-28 18:48:26.348185-0800 KeySnap[2446:10989] [MC] Reading from 
private effective user settings.
2018-02-28 18:48:28.663829-0800 KeySnap[2446:11411] [discovery] errors 
encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit 
Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query 
cancelled}
actual_tessdata_num_entries_ <= TESSDATA_NUM_ENTRIES:Error:Assert 
failed:in file tessdatamanager.cpp, line 53
(lldb)
```

Im using the tesseract cocoapod to include the library via the follow pod file script which matches my ios version

```
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'KeySnap' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'TesseractOCRiOS'
end
```

Comment: I'm trying to copy the code from your question, but I can't figure out how to paste it into a file from an image. How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: sorry for not including the code, Not certain you could actually run any of this without the full library but I've included it regardless

Answer (score 0):

figured it out no thanks goes to the snarky comments about my screenshots.

The English trained data file does not work. If you are using the latest eng.trained file then you will get this error.  I had to use an old version as well as a number of other files associated with the trained language which was available via this tutorial.
[raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/163445/tesseract-ocr-tutorial-ios)

Comment: Tessdata files for tesseract 3.* are located [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/tree/3.04.00) and for 4.* [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_best) and [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/tree/4.00)